# mongdb match when some variables is exist, if its not exist , do not match with it

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
let list = await TDataModel.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      device_id,
      createdAt: { $gte: startTime, $lte: endTime }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { createdAt: -1 }
  }
])
```

when the device_id is exist, i want match with it, but when it not exist(it was null), i want match without it. do you have some good suggestion.

now, i am doing with that

```
let list = []
if (device_id) {
list = await TDataModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          device_id,
          createdAt: { $gte: startTime, $lte: endTime }
        }
      },
      {
        $sort: { createdAt: -1 }
      }
    ])
} else {
list = await TDataModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          createdAt: { $gte: startTime, $lte: endTime }
        }
      },
      {
        $sort: { createdAt: -1 }
      }
    ])
}
```

even it can resolve my problem,but i think there must be a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is fine, however we can just make it a little sexier via some sugar syntax in the [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Conditional) operator

```
let list = await TDataModel.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                device_id ? device_id : {},
                {
                    createdAt: { $gte: startTime, $lte: endTime }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { createdAt: -1 }
    }
])
```

Comment: This is the result i want

i change it, device_id ? {device_id} : {}, and it works, thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can created a variable and store your conditions in it,

- created `match` variable, if `device_id` not null then add in match variable

```
let match = { createdAt: { $gte: startTime, $lte: endTime } };
if (device_id) match.device_id = device_id;

let list = await TDataModel.aggregate([
  { $match: match },
  { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } }
])
```

Comment: thanks you first,
yeap，this is a better way, it's also can resolve my problem, but i am thinking about weather we can write some expression inside $match

Comment: i don't think its better way because, it will affect query processing and condition checking time in fetch the records.